# How to use the output of task1 in another task2?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I want to use the output from `task calc(ton,toff)` into task `clk_gen`, but the output from `clk_gen` is ton = 0 , toff = 0.

```
Question 1: why it is not ton = 24 ,ton =16
Question 2: why it is not ton = x  ,ton = x
Question 3: why it is  ton = 0 ,toff = 0
```

*having clk period of clk as 40 ns*
*having clk period of clk2 as 10 ns*

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module newm();
reg clk=0;
real  period = 40;
reg clk2 =0;
always #5 clk2 = ~ clk2;
```

*calculating ton and toff from task : calc*

```
task calc(input real dutycycle,input real period,output real ton,output real toff);
ton = dutycycle * period;
toff = (1-dutycycle) * period ;
$monitor("values inside calc,  ton = %0d ,toff = %0d",ton,toff);// output :values inside calc ,ton = 24,toff = 16
endtask
```

*using ton and toff at clk_gen*

```
task clk_gen(input real ton,input real toff);
$monitor("values inside clk_gen ,ton = %0b ,toff = %0b",ton,toff);   // ----- why ? output:values inside clk_gen ,ton = 0,toff = 0 
@(posedge clk2);
forever begin
clk =1;
#ton;
clk= 0;
#toff;
end
endtask
```

*running the code*

```
reg ton;
reg toff;  
  
initial begin
calc(0.6,period,ton,toff);
clk_gen(ton,toff);
end 
initial begin
#200;
$finish();
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

In module `newm`, you declared `ton` and `toff` as 1-bit variables, but you should have declared them as type `real`.  Verilog converts 24 to 0, which is why you see 0 inside the `calc_gen` task.

Change:

```
reg ton;
reg toff;
```

to:

```
real ton;
real toff;
```